# Swift 3.0 how to use startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: withHandler)?

Tags: scenekit, core-motion, swift3, xcode8, ios10

Swift 3.0 was released alongside Xcode 8.0 and apparently a lot has changed. I'm very unfamiliar with the new syntax in swift. Can someone help me out? I'm trying to figure out what goes in

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(
        to: OperationQueue.current()!,
        withHandler: )
```

after the "withHandler:"

I am trying to get my SceneKit program be able to utilize the accelerometer to determine the orientation of an SCNNode platform. I am also fairly new to swift (about 5 days into programming in Swift) so if there's something fundamental I am messing up, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:)

> You must pass the block that conforms the CMDeviceMotionHandler type.

```
 motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current()!, withHandler:{
                deviceManager, error in
                //Do stuffs with deviceManager or with error

            })
```

Comment: Yeah, I was about to answer the question myself since i just figured it out, thanks by the way!