# Using startDeviceMotionUpdates under Swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-motion

Yes, I have seen a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850229/swift-3-0-how-to-use-startdevicemotionupdatesto-withhandler) on this, but I still can't get this to work. My previous Swift2 code was...

```
motionMgr.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: handleMove)
```

which called:

```
func handleMove(motion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) {
    ...
}
```

This has changed under Swift3, and now the `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue` uses a closure. I can't for the life of me figure out how to call my existing method. I realize the `NSError` became `Error` and other minor changes, but the syntax of the call from the closure has me very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, there are just a few re-namings in Swift 3.

```
motionMgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue(), withHandler: handleMove)

func handleMove(motion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) {
    // ...
}
```

The `handler` is of type `CMDeviceMotionHandler` which is defined as a `typealias` to a closure:

```
typealias CMDeviceMotionHandler = (CMDeviceMotion?, Error?) -> Void
```

We just need to provide a closure (or a function, since a function is a closure), that takes in two parameters (a `CMDeviceMotion?` and `Error?`) and returns nothing (`Void`).

Alternatively, you could provide a closure instead of a function like so:

```
motionMgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue(), withHandler: { deviceMotion, error in
    // ...
})
```

or use the new trailing closure syntax:

```
motionMgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { deviceMotion, error in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nathan. The key, for me, was the trailing syntax, which I found much easier to grok. I simply put the func call in the trailing closure and that was that!

Comment: motionMgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xTrueNorthZVertical, to: OperationQueue()) {
    deviceMotion, error in self.handleMove(motion: deviceMotion, error: error)
   }